# Wrong division, right result

Tags: number-theory

If we divide in the following way (why MathJax `\cancel` doesn't work on this page?):
$$\require{cancel}
\frac{1\cancel{\color{red}{6}}}{\cancel{\color{red}{6}}4}=\frac{1}{4}\qquad\text { ``dividing'' by 6}
$$
we obtain the correct result. Another example is 
$$
\frac{1\color{red}{6}\color{cyan}{3}}{\color{cyan}{3}2\color{red}{6}}=\frac12.
$$
Is there a method of finding more such examples?

**Edit:** I wish to thank @amWhy for the immediate help. I am leaving the unchanged question to future users with the same problem.

Comment: You need to declare it before using it (only one such declaration needed: `$\require{cancel}$`.

Comment: @amWhy Is `\require`  for a package or a command? (For the future usage).

Comment: Any fraction that includes two multiples of $10$ work if you take away the $0$'s.

Comment: `\require` requires a package. Of course it only works for some packages.

Comment: This is called "Anomalous Cancellation". Relevant pages: https://oeis.org/A159975 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnomalousCancellation.html and https://benvitalenum3ers.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/fractions-anomalous-cancellation/ (the last one just because it gave me the term)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011233/explain-how-and-why-the-cancellation-of-6-s-in-dfrac1664-to-get and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49657/bad-fraction-reduction-that-actually-works and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512373/anomalous-cancellation-definition